# Warning: Directory name too long.:

Tags: matlab, parameters, curve-fitting, fminsearch

I am trying to apply a fitting procedure for a very difficult function which actually is

```
||F(theoretical)-F(experimental)||^2.
```

I need to fit about 12 parameters. I decided not to print this function cause it contains about 20K chars.  To do fitting I use `fminsearch`. Right after start I receive a very long message which states:

> Warning: Directory name too long.:
>   %D:\upcon_1.m>fit_all_Callback/(here is a full code of my function)

And after about 4 seconds after start matlab becomes suspended and windows shuts it down.
What is a reason for it?

Thanks in advance for every response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see/don't want to see your code, but the warning message suggests that you've somehow written your code to tell MATLAB to slurp the contents of your file as a string and treat it as a path! I'd suggest you put a breakpoint in the first line of your code and step through it line by line until you find the offending command.
Brett

Comment: Yes, I have looked through the code and I haven't find any place where I can occasionally print my code to the file, except one - if i delete the string with a function fminsearch there is no "warning". So the problem is in the fminsearch function, but I use it correctly. It is strange.